# string to vector conversion throws std::bad_alloc

Tags: c++, string, vector, std

I am having trouble creating a vector from a string. Can someone explain me the difference between the 4 cases below? According to [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/) I expected `Case 1` to work the same as `Case 2` does for same weird reason, but it doesn't.

```
typedef std::vector<uint8_t> uint8vec_t;

std::string keySecret ()
{
    return std::string ("SomeSecret");
}
```

Case 1

```
// throws std::bad_alloc
uint8vec_t vSecret (keySecret ().begin (), keySecret ().end ());
```

Case 2

```
// results in a vector with strange length
uint8vec_t vSecret (keySecret ().begin (), keySecret ().begin () + keySecret ().length ());
```

Case 3

```
// throws std::bad_alloc
uint8vec_t vSecret (&keySecret ()[0], &keySecret ()[keySecret ().length ()]);
```

Case 4

```
// throws std::bad_alloc
uint8vec_t vSecret (&keySecret ()[0], &keySecret ()[0] + keySecret ().length ());
```

Comment: Your spacing is... uhm... let's call it... untraditional (and incredibly confusing to read).

Comment: @rubenvb, it's GNU style, http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html#Formatting but I don't like it for C++ at all

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They're all bad, you just happened to get what looks like correct behaviour in the second case. The problem is that `keySecret` returns a different `std::string` object each time. You can't call `begin` on one and `end` on another and expect them to be related in any way.

You should instead call `keySecret` once, make a local copy, then call `begin` and `end` on that single local object.

Answer (score 3):

After the two calls to `keySecret()` you have two different strings in memory:

```
...x..x....SomeSecret\0..x.x.x...x..x..x.x...SomeSecret\0....x.x..x.x..
           ^         ^                       ^         ^
           begin1    end1                    begin2    end2
```

You are then trying to create a vector using either

```
vector<char> v(begin1, end2);
```

or

```
vector<char> v(begin2, end1);
```

(depending which string happens to be earlier in memory and which gets returned by which `keySecret()` call).

The first will allocate `end2 - begin1` bytes and copy `"SomeSecret\0..x.x.x...x..x..x.x...SomeSecret\0"` into that memory, with some arbitrary number of bytes between the two iterators, containing whatever happens to be in memory between the strings. This is undefined behaviour, due to reading past the end of the memory allocated for the first string.

The second will try to find the distance `end1 - begin2` which is negative, so wraps to a very large unsigned number, and trying to allocate that many bytes fails, throwing a `bad_alloc` exception.

In both cases, performing pointer arithmetic on two unrelated pointers that point to distinct objects is undefined behaviour, so in theory anything can happen. In practice the results can be explained fairly logically, as above (although a segfault wouldn't be a surprising result for the first case instead of a vector with the wrong contents).